# Voice to Text conversion in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

Currently i am working on a project where it has to get user voice as input and it has to be converted to text in real time. I tried many sample projects in JAVA Sphinx, but am struggling with the part of writing a grammar file. So if there is any possible way of doing this in SWIFT3, please help me with it?

Comment: You must  [see](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/) this

Answer (score 2):

Now from the `iOS10`, Apple provides the best solution of this problem for iOS developers. Now you can integrate your app with the `SiriKIt`, [Tutoiral here](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/). Its all `Siri's` responsibility to manage the text-to-voice recognization, and advantage of using this kit is that,

1. it is getting more powerfull as the  iOS versions are updating and once you integrates this, there is no need to change your code work
2. your line of code is also less as compare to use third party.
3. You don't need to manage the kit as you do with third , its all apple duty to manage everything about `SiriKit`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can use `SFSpeechRecognizer` to convert voice to text

First of all `import Speech` framework in your `.swift` file.

Then respond to the delegate `SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate` like this

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {
```

then declare the below properties

```
private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))!

private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?

private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
```

After this things, make sure you have access to `Speech recognition`

Now use this code to convert voice to text

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else { fatalError("Audio engine has no input node") }
guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else { fatalError("Unable to created a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object") }

// Configure request so that results are returned before audio recording is finished
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

// A recognition task represents a speech recognition session.
// We keep a reference to the task so that it can be cancelled.
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
    var isFinal = false

    if let result = result {

        //Here the the text of your voice
        print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
        isFinal = result.isFinal
    }

    if error != nil || isFinal {
        self.audioEngine.stop()
        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

        self.recognitionRequest = nil
        self.recognitionTask = nil

    }
}

let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
}

audioEngine.prepare()

try audioEngine.start()
```

Disclaimer - The code has been taken from - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Hi, in this there comes an error saying that speechrecignizer is not availabe when making a object from  SFSpeechRecognizer

Comment: Yes  I imported it, but still there comes the error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have not done much research over this topic.

Any ways there are many ways you can achieve what you want... Like:

- Use Speech framework by apple itself. You will  get tutorials for speech frame work [here](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/) and [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri) also you can look at the framework details over [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech)
- Use [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) (its a open source library for speech recognition)

Hope this will help you :)